# Google Play Developer API - In-app update priority does not work

Tags: java, android, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to set in-app update priority parameter for publishing new android app build to the Play Store. According to this documentation it should work:

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates
2. https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/model/TrackRelease.html

But actually it doesn't. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Here is an example:

```
// creating AndroidPublisher instance in some way
AndroidPublisher androidPublisher = createPublisher(serviceKeyPath);

// creating new edit
AppEdit edit = androidPublisher.edits()
    .insert(APP_PACKAGE, null)
    .execute();
String editId = edit.getId();

// uploading APK
FileContent apkContent = new FileContent(APK_MEDIA_TYPE, new File(apkPath));
Apk apk = androidPublisher.edits()
    .apks()
    .upload(APP_PACKAGE, editId, apkContent)
    .execute();

// preparing release info
List<Long> versionCodes = Collections.singletonList(apk.getVersionCode().longValue());
TrackRelease trackRelease = new TrackRelease()
    .setName(getNewVersionName())
    .setReleaseNotes(getReleaseNotes())
    .setVersionCodes(versionCodes)
    .setStatus("completed")
    .setInAppUpdatePriority(5); // <-- value from 0 to 5
Track track = new Track()
    .setTrack("internal")
    .setReleases(Collections.singletonList(trackRelease));

// submitting new release info to the edit
Track savedTrack = androidPublisher.edits()
    .tracks()
    .update(APP_PACKAGE, editId, "internal", track);
```

As a result the value of 'updatePriority' field should be 5. But Google Play Developer API returns NULL:

```
TrackRelease savedRelease = savedTrack.getReleases().get(0);
System.out.println("Update priority: " + savedRelease.getInAppUpdatePriority());
```

Output:

```
Update priority: null
```

It is NULL even after creating a new release:

```
// publishing 
AppEdit validatedAppEdit = androidPublisher.edits()
    .commit(APP_PACKAGE, editId)
    .execute();
```

Then waiting for some time. A new build is live on the Play Store. Now:

```
// creating new edit, it will contain the state of the latest release
AppEdit edit = androidPublisher.edits()
    .insert(APP_PACKAGE, null)
    .execute();

androidPublisher.edits()
    .tracks()
    .get(APP_PACKAGE, edit.getId(), "internal")
    .execute();
TrackRelease release = track.getReleases().get(0);
int priority = release.getInAppUpdatePriority();
System.out.println("Update priority of the latest release: " + priority);
```

Output:

```
Update priority of the latest release: null
```

Also I'm trying to get the update availability status by using Play Core android library in the Android app:

```
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);
appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo()
    .addOnSuccessListener(info -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Update priority: " + info.updatePriority());
        if (info.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && info.updatePriority() > 4
            && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
            // starting immediate update flow here
        }
    });
```

But actually updatePriority() method returns 0. Expected value: 5.

Other methods work correctly: updateAvailability() returns UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE as expected.

Comment: how can i use these edits commands and where i should to put it ?? i can't find a tutorial for that .. help ls